# Time between status reports with pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataset the contains the status changes of one of our companies' systems.
I am only able to use PySpark to process this data.

each row in the dataset is a status change. There is a status column and an update timestamp.

| Status | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| red | 2023-01-02T01:05:32.113Z |
| yellow | 2023-01-02T01:15:47.329Z |
| red | 2023-01-02T01:25:11.257Z |
| green | 2023-01-02T01:33:12.187Z |
| red | 2023-01-05T15:10:12.854Z |
| green | 2023-01-05T15:26:24.131Z |

For the sake of what I need to do, we are going to say a degradation is the first time it reports anything not green to the time it reports green again. What I am trying to do is to create a table of degradations with the duration of each one. ex:

| degradation | duration | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| degradation 1 | 27.65 | 2023-01-02T01:05:32.113Z | 2023-01-02T01:33:12.187Z |
| degradation 2 | 16.2 | 2023-01-05T15:10:12.854Z | 2023-01-05T15:26:24.131Z |

I can get PySpark to return durations between two timestamps without an issue, what I am struggling with is getting PySpark to use the timestamp from the first red to the following green and then log it as a row in a new df.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have one solution. Dont know if this is the easiest and fastest way to calculate what you want. For me the problem is that those data are valid only when they are not partitioned and in correct order which forces me to move all of them to one partition, at least at first stage

What i am doing here

I am using one big window with lag function and sum to calculate new partitions. In this case partition are created base on occurence of record with status = 'green'

Then i am using group by to find first/last event within each partition and calculate the diff

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = [
    {"Status": "red", "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 1, 5, 32, 113)},
    {"Status": "yellow", "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 1, 15, 47, 329)},
    {"Status": "red", "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 1, 25, 11, 257)},
    {"Status": "green", "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 1, 33, 12, 187)},
    {"Status": "red", "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 5, 15, 10, 12, 854)},
    {"Status": "green", "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 5, 15, 26, 24, 131)},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("timestamp")

df.withColumn(
    "partition_number",
    F.sum(
        (F.coalesce(F.lag("Status").over(windowSpec), F.lit(0)) == F.lit("green")).cast(
            "int"
        )
    ).over(windowSpec),
).groupBy("partition_number").agg(
    F.first("timestamp", ignorenulls=True).alias("start"),
    F.last("timestamp", ignorenulls=True).alias("end"),
).withColumn(
    "duration",
    (F.round((F.col("end").cast("long") - F.col("start").cast("long")) / 60, 2)),
).withColumn(
    "degradation", F.concat(F.lit("Degradation"), F.col("partition_number"))
).select(
    "degradation", "duration", "start", "end"
).show(
    truncate=False
)
```

output is

```
+------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|degradation |duration|start                     |end                       |
+------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|Degradation0|27.67   |2023-01-02 01:05:32.000113|2023-01-02 01:33:12.000187|
|Degradation1|16.2    |2023-01-05 15:10:12.000854|2023-01-05 15:26:24.000131|
+------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

If there is such a need you may change precision in duration or adjust this code to start counting degradation from 1 not 0 if this is a problem

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you!
What this shows me is that I need to get petter at window and partition in PySpark.
Really, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the status `green` first, use `lag` to move a row after. Then you can seperate for each degradation by summing the value over window.

```
w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("timestamp")
df.withColumn('status', f.lag((f.col('status') == f.lit('green')).cast('int'), 1, 0).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('status', f.sum('status').over(w) + 1) \
  .groupBy('status') \
  .agg(
    f.first('timestamp').alias('start'),
    f.last('timestamp').alias('end')
  ) \
  .select(
    f.concat(f.lit('Degradation'), f.col('status')).alias('degradation'),
    f.round((f.col('end') - f.col('start')).cast('long') / 60, 2).alias('duration'),
    'start',
    'end'
  ) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|degradation |duration|start                  |end                    |
+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|Degradation1|27.67   |2023-01-02 01:05:32.113|2023-01-02 01:33:12.187|
|Degradation2|16.18   |2023-01-05 15:10:12.854|2023-01-05 15:26:24.131|
+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```